# How to send text and binary data from a custom netty HTTP server in Java?

Tags: java, http, netty

Based on netty 3.6 I am implementing a small HTTP server into my Java desktop application. By now I have successfully created the basic HTTP server layout, I can send various text-based files to my browser-based clients.

In my netty server pipeline factory I create new channel pipelines as following:

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576));
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpServerHandler());
```

In my `HttpServerHandler` class I send text data to the clients as following:

```
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
response.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, contentType + "; charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader(PRAGMA, "no-cache");
response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(responseText, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

if(keepAlive)
{
    response.setHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.getContent().readableBytes());
    response.setHeader(CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
}

ChannelFuture future = e.getChannel().write(response);
```

Good. Now I additionally want to send binary data (e.g. images) to my clients. Since I found no online example on how to achieve this I have two questions:

1. How do I need to modify the channel pipeline to be able to send both, text and binary data to my clients?
2. How to modify the `HttpServerHandler` class in order to send a binary file to the client?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any more differenece between context or binary. I think what you need to do is set the content-type right. Then browser know how to handle it.

If you want to send a png file to browser, set the content-type to "image/png".